# Why do dogs hold specific objects in their mouth?

Tags: dogs, toys

I found [this Yahoo answer](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100214154957AAbYji9), stating dogs carry specific objects around because of an emotional attachment. I'm curious if they have the ability to form that kind of attachment.

My pug is obsessed with stuffed animals, but usually only plays with one stuffed shark. I haven't been able to pair a few specific situations where she goes to the stuffed shark, it seems random. Sometimes she goes weeks without playing with it, other times it's every day.

Her interest seems to have positive feedback for engagement with it in the near future. That makes me wonder if she's interested in the shark because I'm interested in her when she's playing with it.

Am I looking at...

- Her attachment to an object,
- A sensation,
- Or her attachment to me?

I think it could be useful to know if I am responsible for her habits like this or, if they're intrinsic.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a great question! My dog loved to steal my socks and carry them around, and when somebody came home she sometimes brought a sock to greet you (in which case you should feel very, very honored... :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dogs have emotions. Their intelligence is similar to a 2-3 year old. But they aren't people and don't look at things like people do. For instance, they live in the now instead of holding on to things. They don't sulk and are natural peace keepers.

As far as the shark, I think it's a combination of things. Part of it could be because of you (the attention that you give when you play, her attachment to you which extends to the toy because it might smell like you) but it could also be because of the toy itself. My dogs prefer certain toys (and they're not the same toys either), but it goes in cycles because dogs get bored of toys, too. For one, it's a stuffed grizzly bear. The other loves soft animals with appendages to chew off. My Yorkie would only play with 3 specific toys, because of the noise they made.

Answer (score 1):

We have had three Vizslas over the years and all have had an instinctive need to greet you with an object in their mouth! This could be a slipper, shoe, or other object. Our current Vizsla greets us with a blanket or most recently his dog bed! My daughter has his brother who does the same thing! They are hunting dogs, so I always thought that that was the reason. They’re bringing you their “prey”!